# notepad++ : last character get missed while selecting text

Tags: notepad++

In notepad++, when i double click to select a string and copy it, on pasting last char of that string goes missing. [selection show full highlighted string]
EG: **abcde**-->select-->copy-->paste **abcd**. 
Pls let me know if I am missing any setting here.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.. using COPY ALL FORMAT TO CLIPBOARD is causing the deletion of last character while pasting. Using Raw copy paste will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a problem with the nppexport plugin.
There is a similar report (with a solution modifying the source) here:https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/12875/copy-all-formats-truncating
I did not test the fix, but submitted an issue with the nppexport plugin on github.